# Passing the selectionStart property (monthCalendar) between forms (winforms c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I have a calendar control on one form (statsform) that I am calling from another form exportform:

here is the code in statsform where I instantiate exportform:

```
private void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (formIsHidden == 0)
            {
                ExportForm exportForm = new ExportForm();
                exportForm.Show();
                formIsHidden = 1;
            }

        }
```

I update the date in the calendar control in statsform every time it is clicked:

```
public void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            dateFromLabel.Text = dateFromCalendar.SelectionStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");   
        }

        public void monthCalendar2_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            dateToLabel.Text = dateToCalendar.SelectionStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
        }
```

Here is the code from form2 (trying to get selectionStart Property and use it)

```
(On button click)

statsform statsform = new statsform();

string startDate = statsform.dateFromCalendar.SelectionStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
string endDate = statsform.dateToCalendar.SelectionStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59.00");

(Pass date to SQL Queries)
```

However, the selected date is not passed to exportform, only the current date is passed when i create a breakpoint and inspect the strings.

Is it because I am creating a new instance of the form?  How can I pass the user selected date form the form to the second form?

statsform(create Calendar) -> exportform (button click event - retrieve selectedDate from statsform calendar control)

My solution:

```
public ExportForm(statsform parent)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            statsform = parent;

        }
```

Allowed me to use the existing instance of the form.  I needed the (this) in the constructor though so thanks for all the help.

Comment: Clearly you did not actually mean to use `new statsform()`.  That is a new form object whose calendar the user has not seen yet,. so could not possibly have selected a date on yet.  Use the existing instance, the one that the user is looking at.  Add a field to your form if necessary to store that instance, set it back to null with its FormClosed event.

Comment: How do i use the existing instance in form2?

Comment: You make it too hard to help you, I only see ExportForm and statsform in the snippet.  What "form1" and "form2" might be is unclear.  Pretty hard to make headway in Winforms when the notion of types vs objects is still unclear, it is relentlessly OOPy.   Find it back from Application.OpenForms if you are desperate.

Comment: Sorry.  I was just using the names "form 1" and "form 2" t make things simpler.  I have updated the code.  Form 1 is statsform and form2 is exportform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a parameter on your exportform’s constructor when you instantiate it to pass a reference to your first form, then reference those properties directly.

So inside your exportform’s class

```
private statsform _statsform = null;

public exportform(statsform caller) {
    _statsform = caller;
}
```

Then when you instantiate it

```
ExportForm exportForm = new ExportForm(this);
```

And from your button click code you reference the labels in your statsform

```
var fromDate = _statsform.dateFromCalendar.... etc
```

More info on constructors here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The calendar is in form 1, and I want to pass the selected date to form 2, then use it.  I sort of understand your solution, but could you elaborate a little more.  Sorry.

Comment: If I set that parameter on form1's constructor, then instantiate form1 inside form2's button click method, what am I passing as startDate?  because the calendar control is in form1.

Comment: So, you’d add the constructor logic (the bit at the top of my solution) in form 2 in your example. So in form 1 you’d have 2 calendars and a button, on the button click method you’d create a new form2(startDate, endDate), startDate and endDate would be extracted from your 2 calendar controls

Comment: But the button click event is in form 2.

Comment: I see, so the code in your example, is that running in form 1 or form 2?

Comment: The logic is Form 1(create Calendar) -> Form 2 (button click event - retrieve selectedDate from Form1 calendar control)

Comment: It seems when i instantiate form 1 inside form 2, the form no longer detects changes to the date on form 1.  It just passes the current date.

Comment: Yes. When you create a new statsform, you’re creating a brand new instance of that class. It’s possible to have many instances of the same form open, each of them with the same look and logic, but each of them containing different information. Think of them like contact entries in your phone, they all look the same but John and Fred are two different instances of the same thing...

Comment: ... by creating a new statsform it’s like creating a new contact and therefore you can’t access the information on the instance you have open already. To make this work, you need to pass a reference to the form. I’m assuming your opening your form2 from your form1 is that correct? Could you place a copy of your code that creates and shows form2 in your question?

Comment: I've updated my code.  Thanks for continuing to help me.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this code and when i use `ExportForm exportForm = new ExportForm(this);` as opposed to `ExportForm exportForm = new ExportForm();` my export form loads it no longer loads any of the controls on the form

Comment: Thanks. Sorry yes my bad (it's been a while since I used winforms)

Comment: Thanks for your help!